# visual studio is hiding .js.map files and .js file , only the typescript .ts files are showing ,

Tags: javascript, angular, visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2017

I have used Visual Studio Code in the past for Angular 2, in which if I didn't want to SEE the .js and .js.map files it was a workplace setting place to hide from the IDE.

I'm now on a project in which VS 2017 professional is used with Typescript, jasmine , karma  with Angular 4.   Task Runner etc..

I want to be able to see and delete .js and .js.map files ,  for one karma is notorious for caching ...  not fun.

1. Some similar questions talk about project file in VS
2. others talk about tsconfig
3. perhaps package.json ?

I have been going through a lot of files and I don't get why the files are not around.

Here is my  `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "allowJs":  true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

> That says  `allowJS : true`

**What other file(s) can I paste to show?  what is happening on the compile/build?**

Comment: how are you compiling the ts files as `"compileOnSave": false,` is set?

Comment: if you click on "show all files" under solution explorer and check inside `/dist/out-tsc` you should see the js files provided the path is correct.

Comment: Well, I didn't start/create the project so I am not sure.  I noticed this file and the site works.. with all the typescript code working, along with karma running jasmine spec files

Comment: I show all files, but I don't see the /dist  folder anywhere .. so strange

Comment: if it isn't there then you have to create  one with the `/dist/out-tsc` structure

Comment: seems odd that I have no js files and that folder needs to be created.  is there any examples of this?

Comment: Do you see generated .js files in directory from File Explorer (not Visual Studio)?

Comment: Did you try removing `allowJS : true` line??

Answer (score 0):

It might be a VS Code Setting: `files.exclude`.
Its value might contain a glob pattern that filters your .js files out.

You can find it in:

- User Settings (`%APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json`)
- Workspace Settings (`.vscode\settings.json`)

Comment: The question is about Visual Studio, not Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle that behavior to show the .js files with this button in your Solution Explorer:

[image]